# Load 1 image to multiple ImageView with Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

How to load 1 image from server to multiple imageView using Glide?
i've try this code :

```
Glide.with(ViewProductActivity.this)
        .load(LoginActivity.SERVER_URL+"/product/asset/"+listImageUrl.getString(i))
        .asBitmap()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
        .error(R.drawable.noimage)
        .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                ivImageChild.setImageBitmap(resource);
                ivImageMain.setImageBitmap(resource);
            }
        });
```

but the placeholder() doesn't work.. how to solve?

Comment: post error log.

Comment: no error broh, just doesn't work

Comment: so just place holder is not working or any image?

Comment: just placeholder isn't working.. so when downloading process is working, there's no loading image appear

Comment: is loading is simple image or custom drawable?

Comment: i used same function in my app and i used custom drawable to show progress

Comment: just simple PNG image

Comment: i am using:   Glide.with(context)
                    .load(prod.getImageSrc().trim())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.pb_animview)
                    .error(R.drawable.search)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(holder.iv);             and it is working perfectly

Comment: how to make glide load 1 image to multiple view?

Comment: i think diskCache stratergy is used for that.

Comment: what is holder.iv? is it hold more than 1 imageView?

Comment: No, it is one Imageview. But you can apply same image path for all of its view and use DiskCache staratergy for caching images

Comment: can you give me full code? please

Comment: You are using Adapter or simple activity.?

Comment: simple activity

Comment: Inverce is right. his method is not use much resources.

Answer (score 2):

Simply create request for each image :)

```
Glide.with(ViewProductActivity.this)
  .load(LoginActivity.SERVER_URL+"/product/asset/"+listImageUrl.getString(i))
    .asBitmap()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
    .error(R.drawable.noimage)
    .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
    .into(ivImageChild);

Glide.with(ViewProductActivity.this)
  .load(LoginActivity.SERVER_URL+"/product/asset/"+listImageUrl.getString(i))
    .asBitmap()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
    .error(R.drawable.noimage)
    .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
    .into(ivImageMain);
```

Comment: it uses more bandwidth. So i want to make 1 Glide download process with 2 targets of ImageView

Comment: @zihadrizkyef it doesn't use more bandwidth. Once if you load an image to `ImageView`, it reuses the same from cache, it doesn't call server every time